# How to add Dynamic image/text components to background image along with measures on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm tracking the page clicks on a website and reporting measures on how many visitors click each part of the webpage, source, location, and other attributes.

I'm trying to create a dashboard that kind of looks like the website I have as a background image and names the parts of the website based on a static lookup table with the measures to the side of each part. depending on whether the site is accessed on mobile or desktop, the view changes.

The idea I had is to create multiple worksheets for each page. But the team is going to add more pages to the site. So after selecting the page name, the layout is going to be pretty much the same, but the component names and the colors are going to change. So, it's not an effective solution to keep adding worksheets for each page/layout.

And I have 0 clues where to start. Not looking for a solution here, but need help to drive in the right direction[image]